# Spring data redis mock

Tags: redis, spring-data

I need to do integration testing for a spring cloud application running with spring data on redis.
Tests work locally with the regular redis server instance and I need to run this on a Jenkins CI server that is controlled by the corporate CI engineering group.
Obviously I can attach to a redo server there so I used an embedded redis server (from here: https://github.com/kstyrc/embedded-redis).
Running tests locally with this redis server works well since there is a test profile to inject the embedded server in place of the production one.
Now the problem is that when we run this in the Jenkins environment this is the error we see.

```
/tmp/1430170830037-0/redis-server-2.8.19: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /tmp/1430170830037-0/redis-server-2.8.19)
```

So this version of redis has specific dependency on a specific version of glibc.  I tried a couple of other libraries but they all depend on the same underlying version of the embedded redis server.

Is there a spring data mock framework that can be used to get around this sort of issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might come a little late for you, but there is indeed a Spring Data Mock framework that you can use, which let's you mock repositories (regardless of the specific backend solution) without a real database connection.

Here is a link: https://github.com/mmnaseri/spring-data-mock

Comment: This is now available in central under `com.mmnaseri.utils:spring-data-mock:1.0`. See the Github page.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a high enough version of `libc6`, that is causing the error.

From [How to fix “/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found”? – Super User](https://superuser.com/a/537694/251249):

> That means the program was compiled against glibc version 2.14, and it requires that version to run, but your system has an older version installed. You'll need to either recompile the program against the version of glibc that's on your system, or install a newer version of glibc (the "libc6" package in Debian).

So, you just need to upgrade your `libc6` package. All versions of Ubuntu have at least version 2.15 because it's a faily important package ([reference](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all)).

To upgrade it, use these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6
```

p.s. This is answer from [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found) by [minerz029](https://askubuntu.com/users/176889/minerz029)

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I figured that out but the people who controls the build servers won't update.